# Very slow disk readind on postgres server

Tags: postgresql, linux, hardware, raid

I hava a server for postgres only, its very slow reading on hd, something about 16mb/s or less, checked in iotop while a server overload.

Two scsi disks, i have to check every information by ssh, my questions is:

- Any visible problem on this information below ?
- its in raid ? ( i supose yes )
- What raid controler is ? ( i supose its LSI SAS based MegaRAID driver )
- This controler is right for SCSI disks ?

If more information is needed, i can get by ssh or try contact with the server admin.

**lshw -class disk**

```
*-disk:0                
   description: SCSI Disk
   product: PERC H330 Mini
   vendor: DELL
   physical id: 2.0.0
   bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: 4.25
   serial: 004f7b7013b7c5431d006a173320844a
   size: 1843GiB (1979GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=55b1a344
*-disk:1
   description: SCSI Disk
   product: PERC H330 Mini
   vendor: DELL
   physical id: 2.1.0
   bus info: scsi@0:2.1.0
   logical name: /dev/sdb
   version: 4.25
   serial: 00ceb7c113bcc5431d006a173320844a
   size: 18GiB (20GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=8fcd8a5d
*-cdrom
   description: DVD reader
   product: DVD-ROM DTA0N
   vendor: HL-DT-ST
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@10:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/dvd
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: D3B0
   capabilities: removable audio dvd
   configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

**dmesg | grep -i SATA**

```
[    2.096764] ahci 0000:00:11.4: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    2.120843] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e01000 port 0x91e01100 irq 80
[    2.120846] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e01000 port 0x91e01180 irq 80
[    2.120849] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e01000 port 0x91e01200 irq 80
[    2.120851] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e01000 port 0x91e01280 irq 80
[    2.152230] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x3f impl SATA mode
[    2.193597] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e00000 port 0x91e00100 irq 81
[    2.193599] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e00000 port 0x91e00180 irq 81
[    2.193601] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e00000 port 0x91e00200 irq 81
[    2.193603] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e00000 port 0x91e00280 irq 81
[    2.193605] ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e00000 port 0x91e00300 irq 81
[    2.193608] ata10: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x91e00000 port 0x91e00380 irq 81
[    2.439944] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.511996] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.768204] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.088456] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.408706] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.736965] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.057219] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.377473] ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.697726] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.017984] ata10: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
```

**dmesg | grep -i SCSI**

```
[    0.936678] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    2.092239] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    2.094582] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: [scsi0]: FW supports<96> MSIX vector,Online CPUs: <6>,Current MSIX <6>
[    2.120286] scsi1 : ahci
[    2.120527] scsi2 : ahci
[    2.120665] scsi3 : ahci
[    2.120786] scsi4 : ahci
[    2.192607] scsi5 : ahci
[    2.192877] scsi6 : ahci
[    2.193040] scsi7 : ahci
[    2.193238] scsi8 : ahci
[    2.193398] scsi9 : ahci
[    2.193540] scsi10 : ahci
[    2.235873] scsi0 : LSI SAS based MegaRAID driver
[    2.236524] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     DELL     PERC H330 Mini   4.25 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.236653] scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     DELL     PERC H330 Mini   4.25 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.256552] scsi 0:2:0:0: Direct-Access     DELL     PERC H330 Mini   4.25 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.256846] scsi 0:2:1:0: Direct-Access     DELL     PERC H330 Mini   4.25 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    5.026872] scsi 10:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM DTA0N    D3B0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    5.045281] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    5.045458] sr 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    5.046249] sd 0:2:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    5.046317] sd 0:2:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    5.046366] sr 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[    5.051164] sd 0:2:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    5.072004] sd 0:2:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Executed this test with the server clean, when tested while a overload, the result of fdatasync was 64.243 ops/sec

**sudo ./pg_test_fsync -s 4**

```
O_DIRECT supported on this platform for open_datasync and open_sync.

Compare file sync methods using one 8kB write:
(in wal_sync_method preference order, except fdatasync
is Linux's default)
        open_datasync                                 n/a
        fdatasync                        2986.662 ops/sec
        fsync                            1658.055 ops/sec
        fsync_writethrough                            n/a
        open_sync                        2481.365 ops/sec

Compare file sync methods using two 8kB writes:
(in wal_sync_method preference order, except fdatasync
is Linux's default)
        open_datasync                                 n/a
        fdatasync                        2745.140 ops/sec
        fsync                            1815.813 ops/sec
        fsync_writethrough                            n/a
        open_sync                        1400.128 ops/sec

Compare open_sync with different write sizes:
(This is designed to compare the cost of writing 16kB
in different write open_sync sizes.)
         1 * 16kB open_sync write        2706.499 ops/sec
         2 *  8kB open_sync writes       1317.201 ops/sec
         4 *  4kB open_sync writes        707.112 ops/sec
         8 *  2kB open_sync writes        337.474 ops/sec
        16 *  1kB open_sync writes        196.249 ops/sec

Test if fsync on non-write file descriptor is honored:
(If the times are similar, fsync() can sync data written
on a different descriptor.)
        write, fsync, close              1987.842 ops/sec
        write, close, fsync              1969.664 ops/sec

Non-Sync'ed 8kB writes:
        write                           309827.130 ops/sec
```

Comment: Its Postgres 9.2, should i move the question to serverfault.com ?

Comment: The data you provided is mostly serverfault type stuff, not dba type stuff.  But, all this data seems to be from when the problem is not occuring, so it is not clear how useful it would be there, either.  Where are you getting the 16MB/sec from?  What is overloading the server?  Do you have a slow query log?

Comment: @jjanes Get the 16MB/sec information from "iotop" and "nmon", the base is fragmented, and are lots of queries that are slow, the problemn is that everything in the server is slower than before, to vacuum one or two thousand dead tuples its take 10 minutes or more.